# MYSQL - Replace 0 with a string and non 0 with another string in SQL query output, without Conditionals

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I have a complex string that starts like this: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'columnName' ...`. The result will display a positive or 0 number. What i want is in case it's 0 i want it to print `string1` (instead of 0) and if it's higher than 0, i want it to print `string2` (instead of that number). The caveat is that i don't want to use conditional statements, no `if`s or `case`s. I've been thinking about a replace function, but i don't think it works. After that then maybe a VIEW (virtual table to store the results?) would work? I don't want to alter any original table data in any way, i just want to manipulate the output. I can't figure it out, I'm an SQL beginner. Help?

Comment: If you are a beginner, you should use `CASE`.  That is the right approach.  In addition, `count(*) almost never returns 0.

Comment: i'd say cast your count to varchar then apply replace if really want replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select COALESCE((select  'string1' as s
                  from table1
                   having count(*) < 0 )
                 ,'string2')
```

Above query returns string 1 if there are no records in the table else it returns string 2

Comment: This is not a criticism of a perfectly valid answer, but the fact that this is what you wanted seems like there's a flaw in the premise of the question.  @RestlessC0bra, you appear not to realize that this is *precisely* the same thing as `SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT  1 AS s FROM table1 HAVING COUNT(*) < 0 ) IS NOT NULL THEN 'string1' ELSE 'string2' END;` (or any number of similar constructs).  There is no reason to avoid conditional expressions, since they are logically valid and typically far more intuitive e.g., `SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1),'string1','string2');`

Answer (score 2):

The correct approach is to use `CASE`, but there are other ways:

```
select elt(1 + least(count(*), 1), 'string1', 'string2')
```

`count(*)` almost never returns `0`.  It only returns `0` when there is no `group by` and the table has no rows (or all rows have been filtered out by the `where`.